# How do I switch sides in the Civil War?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is my first time through playing Elder Scrolls and initially I grabbed every quest that has come available...

At first I thought I wanted to be part of the Imperial Legion but I feel like I picked the wrong side and am now regretting my choice.  So...is there any way to un-join the Legion and join up with the Stormcloaks, or will I have to wait and join them next time?

Comment: Funny, I feel like I'm on the wrong side and I picked the Stormcloaks. It's harder to become Thane in non-Stormcloak holds if you are a stormcloak.

Comment: Haha...wonder if I'll feel that way after I join the stormcloaks ;)  Since I'm already a Thane in a couple cities would that hurt my status if I could unjoin the Legion? hmmm

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - well, the simple answer is to help the Stormcloaks conquer that hold! They'll replace the Thane with one more understanding to Stormcloak interests.

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?  You may be able to use the console to switch which side you join.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you've not yet completed [The Jagged Crown](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_%28Imperial%29), you can turn the crown in to Ulfric Stormcloak in the Palace of the Kings in Windhelm to switch sides to the Stormcloaks.

Those that originally sided with the Stormcloaks, at this point can also [switch sides to the Imperial Legion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_(Imperial)) and give the crown to General Tullius in Castle Dour in Solitude.

If you're past that point, it's too late to switch.

Comment: dang! I just finished that..knew I should have waited.  ty

Answer (score 7):

It depends how far along the quest line you are.

There is a quest called [The Jagged Crown](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown) where you have to retrieve.... *drum roll*... the Jagged Crown

Instead of taking it to the quest giver, you can take it to Ulfric Stormcloak to swap allegiance.  I believe this is the only time you can do so.

This also works if you want to swap from Stormcloaks to Imperials.

Comment: thank you, I wonder if it's possible to kill the guy I got the quest from and steal back the crown?

Comment: @Avien that would be interesting to try, but I suspect the answer is no as the quest at that point is considered complete.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much difference between the two, after you finish the questline the Jarls on the opposite side will be replaced. I joined the Legion since Elisif is nicer then Ulfric, and Ulfric hates anyone that's not a nord. As far as I know, there's no way to switch after the Jagged Crown.

Answer (score -1):

You can find soldiers wandering Skyrim that belong to both your side and the others. If you talk to the ones not on your side, they'll ask you to switch.

Comment: This answer isn't a good answer since if you join the Imperials, the Stormcloaks won't say to join them.