# Is there any way I can cancel the Stormcloak quest(s)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I joined the Stormcloaks only for the ability to gain a Trophy (PS3) but figured I would continue with the quests for the hell of it.
When I found that I had to attack the town of Whiterun, I quickly decided that continuing the quests was just not going to happen with me, so I've decided to stop doing them all together.
But, I wondered if there was someway I could just "Give up" on the whole operation. Or if I just have to ignore them. 
I don't want to attack Whiterun, but I also want to get this blasted [Jagged Crown] out of my inventory.

Comment: i would say abandon the quest but im not confident enough with that answer to place it as an answer.

Comment: I think that attacking the Stormcloak soldiers might also serve the purpose as they'll turn against you and any quest given by them will most likely be aborted/auto failed.

Comment: Related: [How do I switch sides in the Civil War?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39771/4797)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bring the Jagged Crown to General Tulius in Solitude's Castle Dour, he'll gladly enlist your traitorous hide.

Comment: Meh, I'll attack them. AND give the Crown to Tulius. Just in case. ;3

Comment: @CamX3 just make sure to do it the other way around in case the quest will get broken.