# Can I Bring Back The Empire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I started the game I joined the Stormcloaks, because it was the only quest I had. I kind of regret joining the Stormcloaks, now, though. I finished "Battle for Whiterun" and now theres a new Jarl and every guard is now a Stormcloak. If I used console commands to delete the main quests, would there be regular guards everywhere, and would Jarl Balgruuf still be Jarl?

Comment: This might help, depending on how far along you are: [How do I switch sides in the Civil War?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39771)

Comment: Ive already switched sides. But nothing changed

Comment: So you joined the Stormcloaks and then turned in the Jagged Crown to General Tullius instead of Ulfric?

Comment: no i used console commands to switch sides. because.. the jagged crown was the second quest i did.

Comment: and the only guards ive ever encountered that arnt stormclock, are guards in whiterun, dawnstar and dead bodys of guards

Comment: Oh, if you’re past the end of the Jagged Crown and you already edited the war in the console... I don’t know. There’s probably a way to fix it. Put the Jarls you want in the Jarl factions, same thing for housecarls... maybe set the [Battle for Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Windhelm) to finished. It sounds complicated.

Comment: It's far, FAR more than complicated.  You basically have to create a mod to do this because the guards will respawn.  I know they respawn because I always kill guards to fill my black soul gems.  Once you leave the town and come back after the respawn period, it'll all reset.  You can't fix this by console commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

It *may* be possible to pull this off with a long, complex series of console commands, but you're as likely to break your game as you are to fix it. Probably more likely.

In terms of normal gameplay, you're past the point of no return, which is the Jagged Crown quest. See this [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39771/108003) for details on switching sides.